# Downloading big file(800MB) from url into GCS bucket using Cloud function

Tags: python, pandas, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

I have written a code which works in my local and then I tried to replicate the same in cloud function. The basic purpose is to download a massive file of around 800 MB to a gcs bucket.

However I am getting the below error:
Function invocation was interrupted. Error: function terminated. Recommended action: inspect logs for termination reason. Additional troubleshooting documentation can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#logging

there is also a warning which precedes the error
Container worker exceeded memory limit of 256 MiB with 256 MiB used after servicing 1 requests total. Consider setting a larger instance class.

It seems that cloudfunction wont be able to download such a big file, is my assumption correct ? What is max limit on CF for such a task i.e download data from URL to GCS (I am aware that GCS bucket can save an object of upto 5TB)

What other options do i have , I tried to change the code to include chunksize option but even doesnt work.

Code snapshot:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import time

url = ""

def main(request):
s_time_chunk = time.time()
chunk = pd.read_csv(url,
                chunksize=1000 ,
                usecols = ['Mk','Cn','m (kg)','Enedc (g/km)','Ewltp (g/km)','Ft','ec (cm3)','year'] )
e_time_chunk = time.time()
print("With chunks: ", (e_time_chunk-s_time_chunk), "sec")
df = pd.concat(chunk)
df.to_csv("/tmp/eea.csv",index=False)

storage_client = storage.Client(project='XXXXXXX')
bucket_name = "XXXXXXX"

bucket = storage_client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
blob = bucket.blob("eea.csv")

blob.upload_from_filename("/tmp/eea.csv")
print('File uploaded to bucket')
print("Success")
return f"OK"
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloud Functions stores data in memory when you download it. Even if you use a file system path, it's an in memory file system and will consume memory.

The solution is to [increase the memory](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/configuring/memory) of your cloud function (try with 1 or 2 Gb). Use the second gen Cloud Functions if you want more granularity and more memory.